# How to disable a Doctrine subscriber in a Symfony command?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I would like to know if it is possible to disable the subscriber inside a command (only during this command) with Symfony.
I need to update a database but, each time an entity is updated, it will trigger the subscriber and take to much time.

The subscriber is useful for a small amount of modification, but not when the entire database is updated.

I use `prePersist`, `preUpdate`, `postUpdate` and `postPersist`. There is some example :

```
<?php

namespace App\EventSubscriber\ElasticSearch;

use App\Entity\Product;
use App\Entity\ProductTranslation;
use App\Service\ElasticSearch\ElasticSearchProductService;
use Cocur\Slugify\Slugify;
use Doctrine\Common\EventSubscriber;
use Doctrine\ORM\Events;
use Doctrine\Persistence\Event\LifecycleEventArgs;

class ProductSubscriber implements EventSubscriber
{
    private ElasticSearchProductService $elasticSearchProductService;

    public function __construct(ElasticSearchProductService $elasticSearchProductService)
    {
        $this->elasticSearchProductService = $elasticSearchProductService;
    }

    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function getSubscribedEvents(): array
    {
        return [
            Events::prePersist,
            Events::preUpdate,
            Events::postPersist,
            Events::postUpdate,
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @param LifecycleEventArgs $args
     */
    public function prePersist(LifecycleEventArgs $args): void
    {
        $product = $args->getObject();

        if (!$product instanceof Product) {
            return;
        }
        $this->slugProduct($product);
    }

    /**
     * @param LifecycleEventArgs $args
     */
    public function preUpdate(LifecycleEventArgs $args): void
    {
        $product = $args->getObject();

        if (!$product instanceof Product) {
            return;
        }

        $this->slugProduct($product);
    }

    /**
     * @param LifecycleEventArgs $args
     */
    public function postUpdate(LifecycleEventArgs $args): void
    {
        $this->initializeElasticSearch($args);
    }

    /**
     * @param LifecycleEventArgs $args
     */
    public function postPersist(LifecycleEventArgs $args): void
    {
        $this->initializeElasticSearch($args);
    }

    /**
     * @param Product $product
     */
    private function slugProduct(Product $product): void
    {
        $product->setSlug((new Slugify())->slugify($product->getTranslations()['fr']->getName() . '-' . $product->getEan() . '-' . $product->getPickRef()));
    }

    /**
     * @param LifecycleEventArgs $args
     */
    private function initializeElasticSearch(LifecycleEventArgs $args): void
    {
        $entity = $args->getObject();

        if (!($entity instanceof Product || $entity instanceof ProductTranslation)) {
            return;
        }

        if ($entity instanceof ProductTranslation) {
            $entity = $args->getObject()->getTranslatable();
        }

        //$this->elasticSearchProductService->initializeDocumentElasticSearch($entity);
    }
}
```

EDIT : I have updated the example. This is the full subscriber. I update a Brand with for example :

```
$this->em->persist($brand);
$this->em->flush();
```

It will activate the subscriber who will update ElasticSearch. But, in one Symfony Command that I made,I have to update 40 000 brands. I would like to update elasticSearch at the end of the command and not update one by one with the subscriber. So I would like to disable (for only this Command) the subscriber.

This is a Doctrine EventSubscriber and I tried

```
$listeners = $this->em->getEventManager()->getListeners("productSubscriber");
foreach ($listeners as $key => $listener) {
    if ($listener instanceof ProductSubscriber) {
        $this->em->getEventManager()->removeEventListener($listener->getSubscribedEvents(), $listener);
    }
}
```

But the subscriber is not removed.

Comment: I have edit the example and rephrase my question.

Comment: My answer should answer your issue. Use EventDispatcher to `removeSubscriber` your ProductSubscriber. You just have to autowire eventdispatcher and your subscriber in your command constructor and do `$this->eventDispatcher->removeSubscriber($this->productSubscriber);`, everything written in your subscriber will not be called and there won't be any call to `elasticSearchProductService`

Comment: The problem is that the subscriber is not from Symfony But from Doctrine subscriber (use Doctrine\Common\EventSubscriber;) and not from EventSubscriberInterface $subscriber

Comment: Can you try to get listeners without argument? Like this `$listeners = $this->em->getEventManager()->getListeners();`